# Simplify the calculation of the sum of this series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to simplify the last product of this sum.  If possible or another way to find this sum\

> $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left((-1)^n\frac{500n^3+750n^2+360n+50}{625n^4+1125n^3+800n^2+190n+24}\right)=\frac{1}{20}\left\{(2-2\sqrt{5})\log(2)+2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-6\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2(2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}})\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-3}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right\}$\

My solution:\

$(A)$....\

$(500n^3+750n^2+360n+50)=(250n^3+425n^2+225n+36)+(250n^3+325n^2+135n+14)=10n(25n^3+35n+12)+3(25n^2+35n+12)+10n(25n^2+15n+2)+7(25n^2+15n+2)=(10n+3)(5n+4)(5n+3)+(10n+7)(5n+1)(5n+2)$\

$(B)$..\

$(625n^4+1125n^3+800n^2+190n+24)=25n^2(25n^2+35n+12)+10n(25n^2+35n+12)+2(25n^2+35n+12)=(25n^2+10n+2)(25n^2+35n+12)=(5n(5n+2)+(5n+2))(5n(5n+4)+3(5n+4))=(5n+1)(5n+2)(5n+3)(5n+4)$\

so:
$\left(\frac{500n^3+750n^2+360n+50}{625n^4+1125n^3+800n^2+190n+24}\right)=\left(\frac{(10n+3)(5n+4)(5n+3)+(10n+7)(5n+1)(5n+2)}{(5n+1)(5n+2)(5n+3)(5n+4)}\right)$
$=\left(\frac{10n+3}{(5n+1)(5n+2)}+\frac{10n+7}{(5n+3)(5n+4)}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{5n+1}+\frac{1}{5n+2}+\frac{1}{5n+3}+\frac{1}{5n+4}\right)$
we find:
$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{500n^3+750n^2+360n+50}{625n^4+1125n^3+800n^2+190n+24}\right)$$\
$$=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{5n+1}+\frac{1}{5n+2}+\frac{1}{5n+3}+\frac{1}{5n+4}\right)
 =\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+2}+\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+3}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+4}$$
and we have :\

(1)
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+1}=\frac{1}{20}\left[2\sqrt{5}\log(3+\sqrt{5})+\log(2)(4-2\sqrt{5})-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-3}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]$
preuve (1):
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+1}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+1}x^{5n+1}|_{x=1}=S(1)$\ where\ $S(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{5n+1}}{5n+1}$
So.. :$S^{'}(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{5n}=\frac{1}{1+x^5}$
then find :  $S(x)=\int S^{'}(x)dx=\int_{}^{}\frac{1}{1+x^5}dx$
$S(x)=\frac{1}{20}\left[(\sqrt{5}-1)\log(x^2+\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}x+1)-(1+\sqrt{5})\log(x^2-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}x+1)+4\log(x+1)-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-4x+\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{4x+\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]$
we have :
$S(0)=0=\frac{1}{20}\left[-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]+c$
$\implies c=-\frac{1}{20}\left[-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]$
So we find :
$S(1)=\frac{1}{20}\left[2\sqrt{5}\log(3+\sqrt{5})+\log(2)(4-2\sqrt{5})-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-3}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]$
$\implies S(1)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+1}=\frac{1}{20}\left[2\sqrt{5}\log(3+\sqrt{5})+\log(2)(4-2\sqrt{5})-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-3}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]$
(2)
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+2}=\frac{1}{20}\left[\sqrt{5}\log\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{3-\sqrt{5}}\right)-4\log(2)-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-3}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]$
preuve(2):
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+2}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{5n+2}}{5n+1}|_{x=1}=S(1)$
where
$S(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{5n+2}}{5n+1}$\

So :
$S(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{5n+2}}{5n+2}\implies S^{'}(x)=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{5n+1}=x\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-x^5)^{n}=\frac{x}{1+x^5}$
then:
$S(x)=\int S^{'}(x)dx=\int\frac{x}{1+x^5}dx$\
$=\frac{1}{20}\left[(1+\sqrt{5})\log(x^2+\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}x+1)-(\sqrt{5}-1)\log(x^2-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}x+1)-4\log(x+1)-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-4x+\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{4x+\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]+c$
we have :
$S(0)=c+\frac{1}{20}\left[-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]$
$\implies c=\frac{1}{20}\left[2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]$
Finally we find :
$S(1)=\frac{1}{20}\left[\sqrt{5}\log\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{3-\sqrt{5}}\right)-4\log(2)-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-3}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+2}$
(3)
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+3}=\frac{1}{20}\left[\sqrt{5}\log\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{3+\sqrt{5}}\right)+4\log(2)-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]$
Preuve(3):
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+3}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{5n+3}}{5n+3}|_{x=1}=S(1)$
where
$S(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{5n+3}}{5n+3}$
So we have :
$ S^{'}(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{5n+2}=x^2\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-x^5)^n=\frac{x^2}{1+x^5}$
$\implies S(x)=\int\frac{x^2}{1+x^5}dx=\frac{1}{20}\left[-(1+\sqrt{5})\log(x^2+\frac{(\sqrt{5}-1)x}{2}+1)+(\sqrt{5}-1)\log(x^2-\frac{(1+\sqrt{5})x}{2}+1)+4\log(x+1)-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-4x+\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{4x+\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right] +c$
we have :
$S(0)=c+\frac{1}{20}\left[-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]=0$
$\implies c=\frac{1}{20}[2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)$
Finally:
$S(1)=\frac{1}{20}\left[\sqrt{5}\log\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{3+\sqrt{5}}\right)+4\log(2)-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]= \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+3}$
(4)
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{5+4}=\frac{1}{20}\left[\sqrt{5}\log\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{3+\sqrt{5}}\right)-4\log(2)-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-3}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]$
preuve (4):
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+4}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{5n+4}}{5n+4}|_{x=1}=S(1)$
where
$S(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{5n+4}}{5n+4}$
So:
$S^{'}(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{5n+3}=\frac{x^3}{1+x^5}$\
$\implies S(x)=\int\frac{x^3}{1+x^5}dx=\frac{1}{20}\left[-(\sqrt{5}-1)\log(x^2+\frac{(\sqrt{5}-1)x}{2}+1)+(\sqrt{5}+1)\log(x^2-\frac{(1+\sqrt{5})x}{2}+1)-4\log(x+1)-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-4x+\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{4x+\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]+c$
we have : 
$S(0)=c+\frac{1}{20}\left[2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]$
$\implies c=-\frac{1}{20}\left[2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]$
Finally we find:
$S(1)=\frac{1}{20}\left[\sqrt{5}\log\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{3+\sqrt{5}}\right)-4\log(2)-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-3}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]= \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+4}$
we have :\

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+1}+\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+2})=\frac{1}{20}\left[3\sqrt{5}\log(3+\sqrt{5})-2\sqrt{5}\log(2)-\sqrt{5}\log(3-\sqrt{5})+4\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-4\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]$
and  :\

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+3}+\frac{(-1)^n}{5n+4})=\frac{1}{20}\left[2\sqrt{5}\log\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{3+\sqrt{5}}\right)+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)(-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}+2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}})+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)(2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}-2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}})-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-3}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]$\

Finally:
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left((-1)^n\frac{500n^3+750n^2+360n+50}{625n^4+1125n^3+800n^2+190n+24}\right)=\frac{1}{20}\left[(2-2\sqrt{5})\log(2)+2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-6\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)+2(2\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}})\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\right)-2\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-3}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}\right)\right]$\

Is there any help in simplifying the result or finding the sum of this series in another way?thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is a partial answer.*

There is point I do not understand. For me
$$\frac{1}{5n+1}+\frac{1}{5n+2}+\frac{1}{5n+3}+\frac{1}{5n+4}=\frac{500 n^3+750 n^2+350 n+50 }{625 n^4+1250 n^3+875 n^2+250 n+24 }$$ which is not the expression you are working.

Back to the problem given in the post
$$625n^4+1125n^3+800n^2+190n+24=0$$ does not show any real root. So write the expression as
$$\frac{500n^3+750n^2+360n+50}{625n^4+1125n^3+800n^2+190n+24}=\frac{500n^3+750n^2+360n+50}{(5n-a)(5n-b)(5n-c)(5n-d)}$$ where $a,b,c,d$ are complex numbers and use partial fraction decomposition to get
$$\frac{500n^3+750n^2+360n+50}{625n^4+1125n^3+800n^2+190n+24}=\frac {k_1}{5n-a}+\frac {k_2}{5n-b}+\frac {k_3}{5n-c}+\frac {k_4}{5n-d}$$ The problem starts to be complex since
the partial sum
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^p \frac {(-1)^n}{5n-a}=\frac{1}{5} \left((-1)^p \,\Phi \left(-1,1,p+1-\frac{a}{5}\right)+\Phi
   \left(-1,1,-\frac{a}{5}\right)\right)$$ where appears the Lerch transcendent function (for which the asymptotics are not the most pleasant - have a look [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10652469.2019.1627530)).

For the time being (be sure that I shall continue), the value of the infinite sum is
$$1.68876362556729891404128608773597318553351101190557646863328498735\cdots$$ which is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators. It does not seem to agree with your last result.

Have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B%28%28-1%29%5En*%2850+%2B+360*n+%2B+750*n%5E2+%2B+500*n%5E3%29%29%2F%2824+%2B+190*n+%2B+800*n%5E2+%2B+1125*n%5E3+%2B++++625*n%5E4%29%2C%7Bn%2C0%2CInfinity%7D%5D).

**Edit**

- If the problem was
  $$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \left(\frac{1}{5n+1}+\frac{1}{5n+2}+\frac{1}{5n+3}+\frac{1}{5n+4} \right)$$ the result would simply be
  $$S=\frac{2}{5} \sqrt{1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}} \pi \approx 1.72961$$
- Hoping that I did not make any mistake copying the last expression in the post, it could simplify as
  $$\frac{1}{100} \left(\left(3 \sqrt{10+2 \sqrt{5}}-2 \sqrt{10-2 \sqrt{5}}\right)
     \pi -10 \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right) \log (2)\right)\approx 0.125136$$

Comment: thank'sThanks for this note, I will review the results again

Answer (score 0):

I made a test with the software and it shows that this series diverges. I suggest you use a comparison test to prove that. For example, observe that $$\frac{500n^3}{625n^4+1125n^3+800n^2+190n+24}<\frac{500n^3+750n^2+360n+50}{625n^4+1125n^3+800n^2+190n+24}$$ and if $\frac{500n^3}{625n^4+1125n^3+800n^2+190n+24}$ diverges, so will the $\frac{500n^3+750n^2+360n+50}{625n^4+1125n^3+800n^2+190n+24}$. It may become simpler then.

Comment: $\sum_{n\geq1}{}\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent but $\sum_{n\geq1}{}\frac{(-1)^n}{n} $ is convergent look the question @ Rafael Barbosa da silva

Comment: I do not agree. The summation is convergent